# How to select multiple ip infos from ip2location ip database?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to select IP info for multiple IP addresses from the database where IP addresses are stored in ranges. Simple row in DB looks like this:

```
 ip_from  |  ip_to   | country_code | city_name
----------+----------+--------------+-----------
        0 | 16777215 | -            | -
 16777216 | 16777471 | AU           | Brisbane
 16777472 | 16778239 | CN           | Fuzhou
```

I need to write a query where I can pass a list of IPs as an integer for example (16777221, 16777490) and it should return a result like the following:

```
 ip       | country_code | city_name
----------+--------------+-----------
 16777221 | AU           | Brisbane
 16777490 | CN           | Fuzhou
```

Currently, I get info for one IP address with following query:
`select * from ip_table where 16777221 <= ip_to order by ip_to limit 1;`

Answer (score 2):

You can join a set generated with `VALUES`.

```
SELECT v.ip,
       i.country_code,
       i.city_name
       FROM (VALUES (16777221),
                    (16777490)) v (ip)
            LEFT JOIN ip_table i
                      ON i.ip_from <= v.ip
                         AND i.ip_to >= v.ip;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=552bedc8b555fa2b8d01b0b68b81bdb9)

If you want to exclude rows where no match in `ip_table` was found, change the left join to an inner join.

Answer (score 0):

Use the IN keyword.

SELECT * FROM ip_table WHERE ip_to IN (16777221, 16777490)